# Calling an async method without await

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm currently calling an `async` method and don't want to `await` it. I don't need the result for the `async` method and don't want to block during IO. However, if there is an error thrown in the `async` method I would like to `catch` it. So far I have:

```
public static void main () {
    MyAsyncMethod().
    ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine(t.Exception),
           TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    //dostuff without waiting for result
}
```

This is not catching the exception thrown in `MyAyncMethod` from `Main`. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There's no try-catch block...?

Comment: If it's "not catching the exception"  what does happen?

Comment: I assumed that Continuewith would "catch" the exception. Atleast, that's what I read but currently my code crashes

Answer (score 2):

async-await and `ContinueWith` can work but it is full of headaches. It is much easier just refactor out your error handling in to a method and put it in there, then you can just call that new method from your main method.

```
public static void main () {
    var task = DoMyAsyncMethod();

   //dostuff without waiting for result

    //Do a wait at the end to prevent the program from closing before the background work completes. 
    task.Wait();

}

private static async Task DoMyAsyncMethod()
{
    try
    {
        await MyAsyncMethod();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

I suspect the real problem you are dealing with is that missing `Wait()` and your program is closing itself before your background work is done processing.

Comment: Our program will always be running on a server so we will never wait. Won't this still block in DoMyAsyncMethod ?

Comment: No, when you hit the `await` the function `DoMyAsyncMethod` will retun a `Task` object, it will not block. It is up to you want you want to do with that `Task`, wait on it, throw it away, it does not matter. A `await` really is just a easier way to do work with a `ContinueWith`, it lets you write async code the same way you write sync code (for example, using a try/catch instead of a `ContinueWith(SomeMethod, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)`).